# textbox com align a direita no print VB

Tags: vb.net

Eu tenho um printdocument com o seguinte comando

```
Dim font1 As New Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular)
e.Graphics.DrawString(txtnome.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 10, 10)
```

E quando eu imprimo o textbox fica da esquerda pra direita, mesmo com a propriedade do textbox com textalign: right.

Como faço para que na impressão fique igual no textbox com o texto vindo da direita pra esquerda?

Answer (score 0):

Penso que o parâmetro `StringFormat` é capaz de resolver o seu problema:

```
Dim sf As StringFormat = New StringFormat()
Dim font1 As New Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular)

sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far
sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far

e.Graphics.DrawString(txtnome.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 10, 10, sf)
```